# Quickest way to get number of lines in a file

Tags: python, unix, sed

I have a very large file. What would be the fastest way to get the line count. Here are some options I considered:

```
wc -l file.txt

sed -n '$=' file.txt
```

For a large file (100GB or larger), what would be the fastest way?

Comment: Fastest way is `gawk 'END {print NR}' file_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [interesting discussion](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/fast-line-count-for-large-files-583991/) about the different options. Benchmarks copied here:

```
0.024 sec (avg) - wc -l file.txt
0.121 sec (avg) - sed -n '$=' file.txt
0.396 sec (avg) - nl file.txt | tac |sed -n 1p | awk '{print $1}
```

Run on a 18 Mb - 500,000 line file.

Comment: The last variant can be written as `nl file.txt | tac | awk '{print $1;exit}'`